# What does the built-in function sum do with sum(list, [])?

Tags: python

When I want to unfold a list, I found a way like below:

```
>>> a = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
>>> a
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
>>> sum(a, [])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

I don't know what happened in these lines, and [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) states:

> `sum(iterable[, start])`
>
> Sums `start` and the items of an `iterable` from left to right and
>   returns the total. `start` defaults to `0`. The iterable's items are
>   normally numbers, and the `start` value is not allowed to be a string.
>
> For some use cases, there are good alternatives to `sum()`. The preferred, fast way to concatenate a sequence of strings is by calling
>   `''.join(sequence)`. To add floating point values with extended
>   precision, see `math.fsum()`. To concatenate a series of iterables,
>   consider using `itertools.chain()`.
>
> New in version 2.3.

Don't you think that start should be a number? Why can `[]` be written here?

```
(sum(a, []))
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> Don't you think that start should be a number?

`start` *is* a number, by default; `0`, per the documentation you've quoted. Hence when you do e.g.:

```
sum((1, 2))
```

it is evaluated as `0 + 1 + 2` and it equals `3` and everyone's happy. If you want to start from a different number, you can supply that instead:

```
>>> sum((1, 2), 3)
6
```

So far, so good.

---

However, there are other things you can use `+` on, like lists:

```
>>> ['foo'] + ['bar']
['foo', 'bar']
```

If you try to use `sum` for this, though, expecting the same result, you get a `TypeError`:

```
>>> sum((['foo'], ['bar']))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    sum((['foo'], ['bar']))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

because it's now doing `0 + ['foo'] + ['bar']`.

To fix this, you can supply your own `start` as `[]`, so it becomes `[] + ['foo'] + ['bar']` and all is good again. So to answer:

> Why `[]` can be written here?

because although `start` defaults to a number, it doesn't *have* to be one; other things can be added too, and that comes in handy for things *exactly like what you're currently doing*.

Comment: `sum` is actually coded to reject strings. It gives the error `TypeError: sum() can't sum strings [use ''.join(seq) instead]`

Comment: @interjay yep, just spotted that when editing the OP and fixed accordingly

Comment: Thank you, I think that I have understood it. :-)

Comment: Can we decide that `sum` adds `sequence of a type` and that `type` so `sum([['foo', 'bar']], [])` return `['foo', 'bar']`  **BUT**  WHY `sum(['foo', 'bar'], 'r')` does not returns `'foobarr'`

Comment: @SIslam because, per the documentation quoted above *"the start value is not allowed to be a string"*.

Comment: Watch out, though - this takes quadratic time! Since `sum` always uses `+`, if you try to use it for list concatenation, it'll build a new intermediate list for each intermediate concatenation, which takes a quadratic amount of copying.

Comment: @user2357112 isn't that implementation-dependent?  It could easily double the underlying array size with every reallocation, and so it would only be linear amortized time.

Comment: @NeilG: The problem is that it still needs to reallocate on every `+`. Doubling the size doesn't save any reallocations unless you're allowed to operate in-place, and `sum` isn't allowed to operate in-place. One potential improvement would be to use `+` for the first addition and `+=` for subsequent additions, since it's probably okay to clobber the result of the first `+`. I'm not sure whether that'd cause issues, though, and I doubt such a change would have much support. You'd get weirdness like `sum([[], ()], [])` working and `sum([(), []], [])` failing.

Comment: @user2357112 I see your point, but it is possible to accumulate everything in-place since the initialize-value `[]` is unnamed, and so an optimizing compiler like pypy can theoretically modify that list.

Comment: @NeilG: Possible, but still problematic. The system would need to have a pretty good understanding of how `+` and `+=` work on the input data to make sure it works in-place while producing results equivalent to if `+` were used. That might be doable for lists, but you wouldn't be able to use either `+` or `+=` to do it, and the edge cases and situations where the optimization breaks down would probably be a lot more confusing than the current behavior. The option is there, but I don't think it's worth taking.

Comment: @user2357112 I agree that the option is there.  I do think that pypy needs to eventually get there to be competitive.

Answer (score 8):

First of all, never use `sum` for concatenating/flattening lists because it's of quadratic time and hence not efficient at all compare to the other ways around. It actually uses a [schlemiel the painter algorithm](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/schlemiel_the_painter%27s_algorithm).

The `sum` function calls the `__add__` attribute of the `start` on each iteration with all the items of an iterable that's been passed as the first argument.

For example :

```
>>> [].__add__([2,3])
[2, 3]
#OR
>>> [] + [1,2,3]
[1, 2, 3]
```

And in this case the result would be a concatenated list of your input lists. From an algorithmic perspective it does the followings:

```
>>> a = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
>>> start = []
>>> for i in a:
...     start += i
... 
>>> start
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Not that you can call the `sum` function on any sequence of objects that have an `__add__` attribute, but note that since the default `start` argument is `0` if your object is not an integer it will raise an `TypeError`. In that case you need to specify a proper `start` for the function.

```
>>> class newObj(object):
...    def  __init__(self,val):
...         self.val = val
...    def __add__(self,item):
...        return '{}_____{}'.format(self.val,item)
... 
>>> 
>>> start=newObj('new_obj')
>>> 
>>> start
<__main__.newObj object at 0x7f75f9241c50>
>>> 
>>> start + 5
'new_obj_____5'
>>> 
>>> 
>>> sum(['1','2','3'],start)
'new_obj_____123'
```

Comment: Thank you, I think that I have understood it. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You sum the `start` with the contents of the iterable you provide as the first argument. `sum` doesn't restrict the `type` of `start` to an int in order to allow for various cases of adding.

Essentially sum does something like this:

```
a = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
sum(a, number)
```

Roughly translates to:

```
number += every value in the list a
```

Since every value in the list `a` is a list this works and the previous summation, when expanded, looks like this:

```
number + [1, 2] + [3, 4] + [5, 6]
```

So if you enter an `int` this will result in an unfortunate `TypeError` because adding an `int` and a `list` is not allowed.

```
1 + [1, 2] == I hope you like TypeErrors
```

However, If you enter a list `[]` it is simply going to join the elements of `a` together and result in the flattened list we know and love.

The value of `start` defaults to `0` an `int` mainly because the most common case of summation is arithmetic.

Comment: Thank you, I think that I have understood it. :-)