# Summing 1-layer deep nested list in python

Tags: python-3.x

I tried the following

```
a = [[1], [2]]
print(sum(a))
```

I was expecting the output

```
[1, 2]
```

But I got thrown an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

---

What's going on here? I understand that sum takes in an iterable, so should'nt it be concatenating the list elements inside `a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [reduce](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reduce-in-python/#:%7E:text=%20Working%20%3A%20%201%20At%20first%20step%2C,is%20returned%20and%20printed%20on%20console.%20More%20) function from `functools`.

Do the following

```
from functools import reduce
a = [[1], [2]]
result = reduce(lambda first,next:first + next,a)
print(result)
```

This will output

```
[1, 2]
```

Also I find [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_sum.asp), that you can use the `sum` method if you pass a start argument.
Like this

```
a = [[1], [2]]
print(sum(a,[]))
```

This works because our `start` is from the same type of our list items.

I don't know why is giving the error, but my guess is that this method uses a start equals 0 to sum the iterable passed if no `start` parameter is given.

e.g

```
f = ['a','b','c']
sum(f)
```

This will raise the `TypeError`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#33>", line 1, in <module>
    sum(f)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `sum` to flat list, you should use:

```
a = [[1], [2]]
print(sum(a, []))
```

Result:

```
[1, 2]
```

---

but use `sum()` to flat them is not good.[In the official document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum):

> To concatenate a series of iterables, consider using itertools.chain().

So you should use:

```
from itertools import chain

a = [[1], [2]]
print(list(chain(*a)))
```

And [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33541947/what-does-the-built-in-function-sum-do-with-sumlist) point that : *"First of all, never use sum for concatenating/flattening lists because it's of quadratic time and hence not efficient at all compare to the other ways around. It actually uses a schlemiel the painter algorithm."*